# ionic keyboard show wrong with ios 12

Tags: ionic-framework, ios12

After clicking on the input box, the keyboard moves up to the top.

environment: ionic 1, cordova 6.5.0, ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1, ios 12.1.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because your current `ionic-webview` plugin ***mismatches*** with iOS 12.1.

**FIX:**

Remove `ionic-webview` & `ionic-keyboard` plugins, then install those plugins again with following versions since you are working **ionic v1** project.

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
```

Update platforms and try it again. Hope this might help u.

Comment: I recommend you could also update your global `cordova` upto 8.x - latest.

Comment: thanks. But it didn't work! This seems to be related to the version of Xcode 10？Because app build by Xcode 9 is correct.

Comment: well, xcode version does matter and since March 27 2019 you can't upload to app store with xcode9